# Show/Hide button works but just for sec. (javascript-css-html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that **hides/shows** a `div`. In CSS I  wrote `display:none;` for this `div` because I don't want it shown when the page is first loaded. My button works with JavaScript func, and this func including `if-else` and changing the div's display.

The problem is that when I use the button my div is showing for 1 second and it disappears again.

I think it is about my CSS style but JavaScript must have changed the display. So I don't know :( Here is my code (I'm not adding my CSS because it just has `display:none;` about that div)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="butondiv">
    <button id="btnshow" class="btn" onclick="toggle_visibility('panelid')" runat="server"> Departments </button>
</div>
    <div id="panelid" class="panel" style="display:none;">
      <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a>Dep1 </a> <button runat="server" href="#">Delete</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a>Dep2 </a> <button runat="server" href="#">Delete</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a>Dep3 </a> <button runat="server" href="#">Delete</button></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Your code works fine for me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t11vw.gif)

Comment: There might be something other than the code you posted affecting this. Works fine in this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QExvmG

Comment: Are you using `<button>` inside `<form>`? It might submit it.

Comment: @Maxx yes i have form tags, all the things (in body section) in form tags.

Comment: @Joe Interesting, i'm checking again

Comment: Your button submits form and page reload happens

Comment: Check it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzamBq <form> added

Comment: Are you using angular ? Or any other web framework?

Comment: I dont now how, but i added the type="button" in button tag and it works perfectly now (it is the Mr. Joao's answer) Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent the form submission by explicit adding the **type of the button** or by js.

```
<div class="butondiv">
    <button type="button" id="btnshow" class="btn" onclick="toggle_visibility('panelid')" runat="server"> Departments </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution. I'd never think about here :/ But im wonder about the @joe 's answer (in first answer comment) he tryed it on pen. Look at there, there is no type in there too but it works on there. İm counfused on that. But my code works now and thank you Mr. Joao

Answer (score 0):

Try adding e.preventDefault(); - I suspect it's reloading the page and starting with a hidden element again. preventDefault stops the page from reloading.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

EDIT (take 2):

Switch things round so you can get a handle on the event and prevent the page from reloading:

```
document.getElementById("btnshow").addEventListener("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var e = document.getElementById("panelid");
if (e.style.display == 'block') 
  e.style.display = 'none';
else
  e.style.display = 'block';
});
```

You can also remove the onclick="toggle_visibility('panelid')" from the html.

Comment: `e` is undefined here

Comment: I've refactored so you can get to the event and stop it reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="butondiv">
    <button id="btnshow" class="btn" onclick="toggle_visibility('panelid')" runat="server"> Departments </button>
</div>
    <div id="panelid" class="panel" style="display:none;">
      <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a>Dep1 </a> <button runat="server" href="#">Delete</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a>Dep2 </a> <button runat="server" href="#">Delete</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a>Dep3 </a> <button runat="server" href="#">Delete</button></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```